# Adding weights to SharpeRatio in PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

Using the example from `PerformanceAnalytics.pdf` of

`SharpeRatio(edhec, Rf = 0, FUN="VaR" , method="modified")` I get a return per unit of `(VaR)` risk based on (I assume) an equal weighted portfolio assumption,
BUT when I try to add WEIGHTS:

```
weights <- rep(1/13,13)

SharpeRatio(edhec, Rf = 0, FUN="VaR" , method="modified", portfolio_method="component",weights = weights)
```

I get errors :

```
"Error in match.fun(FUNCT)(R, Rf = Rf, p = p, weights = weights, portfolio_method = "single",  : 
  formal argument "portfolio_method" matched by multiple actual arguments"
```

Does anybody know how (form) to expand the `SharpeRatio` function to incorporate portfolio weights?

Comment: There is no _portfolio_, really. `SharpeRatio(edhec)` just evaluates the ratio on each column: compare with `SharpeRatio(edhec[, 1:2])`. Weights mean something else in this context, though I do not know what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that SharpeRatio has difficulty creating the portfolio given the components and the weights.  A solution is to give SharpeRatio the weighted portfolio.  If the portfolio is the weighted combination of the components at each time point( which appears to be what SharpeRatio would calculate), you could use

```
Rf <- 0
SharpeRatio((zoo(edhec) -Rf) %*% weights, FUN="VaR", method="modified")
```

where edhec is first converted to a zoo time series to allow the weights calculation. 
For portfolios with perhaps a more realistic time dependence, you could first calculate the portfolio with, for example, quarterly rebalancing, and then use SharpeRatio

```
port <- Return.portfolio(edhec, weights, rebalance_on = "quarters")
SharpeRatio(port, Rf=Rf, FUN = "VaR", method="modified")
```

Comment: Thanks Walt - a helpful tip from the portfolio angle.  What I shall try to rank each component is [ return of each investment * portfolio weight = contribution to portfolio return from each investment ] divided by Contribution to ES for each investment, to calc a return contribution for each investment per unit of contribution to portfolio ES (tail risk).

Comment: In fact - having tried manually (in R) to produce a return-contribution-per-unit-of-MVaR-contribution style Sharpe ratio I discovered why this is not meaningful in a portfolio context - some  portfolio components may be negative contributors (diversifiers) to the total portfolio MVaR and hence the resulting 'Sharpe' metric, and component ranking thereon, can be misleading e.g. a positive return contribution divided by a negative (diversifying/beneficial) MVaR contribution gives a negative result although the component contributes AND diversifies in the portfolio.